# Are open subsets of a $\sigma$-compact LCH space $\mathcal{K}$-analytic?

Tags: gn.general-topology, complex-geometry, measure-theory, several-complex-variables

I'm reading Guedj and Zeriahi's *Degenerate Complex Monge-Ampère Equations* Chapter 4 which talks about capacities. Specifically Corollary 4.13 claims that when $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact (this conditions is not stated in the book but definitely necessary I think) topological space every open subset $A \subseteq X$ is $\mathcal{K}$-analytic, see below for the definitions.

The book claims that any open subset will be $\sigma$-compact but this [doesn't seem to be true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788960/let-x-locally-compact-and-sigma-compact-then-any-open-subset-is-also-sig#2789771). There can still be hope that this works though, since $\mathcal{K}$-analytic spaces don't need to be $\sigma$-compact in general.
Is the book's claim true?

**Definitions:**

1. A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma\delta}$ if it is a countable intersection of countable unions of closed sets.
2. A topological space $X$ is a $\mathcal{K}_{\sigma\delta}$ space if it is homeomorphic to a $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma\delta}$-subset of a compact space $Y$.
3. A topological space is $\mathcal{K}$-analytic if there is a $\mathcal{K}_{\sigma\delta}$-space that continuously surjects onto it.

**Remark:** If you add the extra assumption of $X$ being 2nd-countable (which is a property inherited to open subsets and implies $\sigma$-compactness for LCH spaces) then indeed every open subset is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Every locally compact space is an open subset of a compact space. And some locally compact (or even discrete) spaces are not K-analytic. Perhaps Guedj and Zeriahi assume that their spaces are metrizable?

Comment: To reinforce what user95282 is saying, a Hausdorff K-analytic space is Lindelöf (see [Fremlin's *Measure Theory*](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/chap42.pdf), volume 4, Theorem 422G (g)). Therefore a discrete space is K-analytic iff it is countable. So the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space is a counterexample.